# Docker multistage build - why not caching layer?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to speed up my [docker multistage build](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/).

In the first stage I copy `.` (except stuff in `.dockerignore`) and build. I deliberately use `COPY . .` so I don't have to list theinteresting folders & to avoid COPY flattening. A `Dockerfile` snippet is at end of this post.

I thought the `RUN rm -rf nginx/` would mean in development if I changed a file in `nginx/` and I rebuild the image that the first stage would be skipped. But that is not working and it is rebuilding it which is slow. Am I misunderstanding how the caching works? Basically I am trying to make changes to the `nginx/` and it is slow to rebuild everything to try stuff. Is there a way to avoid rebuilding the first layer if I change something in `nginx/`?

```
FROM myimage/node:14.19.3 as build
WORKDIR /home/node

COPY . .
# During development NGINX changes should not rebuild this layer;
RUN rm -rf nginx/

RUN npm run build

FROM myimage/nginx:1.23.3
 
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
// SNIP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In short

The fact that you copy all the files and folders with `COPY . .` in your directory, invalidates the cache when you modify any file (even unrelated ones) in this folder.  Cache will be recreated starting from the layer where your edited file has a relevance.

In this case `the relavance` is the fact that your changed on nginx.conf invalidates the layers, because the copy of `.` copies all the files, even the `.conf`, and the deriving layer, in terms of Checksum **cannot** so the layer cannot be the same.

[This answer explain how the checksum of layers are calculated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48161345/20778164)

### TL; DR;

To do a better explanation of what is happening, and due to the fact i don't know what is in your app, i will go with a similar example of mine.

A simple React app, so, let's get in.

In this example there is a copy of specific directories:

```yaml
FROM node as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim
RUN npm install

# pay attention to the following file
# i put this BEFORE all other folders
COPY  ./uselessfile.txt ./veryuseless.txt
COPY ./node_modules ./node_modules  
COPY ./public ./public
COPY ./src ./src
# not really necessary because we launch the npm run build
COPY ./build ./build

RUN npm run build

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

when i launch the build of `docker build -t deusdog .` i will obtain this:

```bash
=> [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 385B                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:latest                                                                       0.5s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                    1.7s
 => => transferring context: 3.21MB                                                                                                  1.4s
 => [ 1/13] FROM docker.io/library/node@sha256:fc738db1cbb81214be1719436605e9d7d84746e5eaf0629762aeba114aa0c28d                      0.0s
 => CACHED [ 2/13] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [ 3/13] COPY package*.json /app/                                                                                          0.0s
 => [ 4/13] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim                                                                             5.0s
 => [ 5/13] RUN npm install                                                                                                         35.4s
 => [ 6/13] COPY  ./uselessfile.txt ./veryuseless.txt                                                                                0.9s 
 => [ 7/13] COPY ./node_modules ./node_modules                                                                                      20.2s 
 => [ 8/13] COPY ./public ./public                                                                                                   0.0s 
 => [ 9/13] COPY ./src ./src                                                                                                         0.0s 
 => [10/13] COPY ./build ./build                                                                                                     0.0s 
 => [11/13] RUN npm run build                                                                                                       20.6s 
 => exporting to image                                                                                                              56.1s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                             56.0s 
 => => writing image sha256:349b2709592f57b9b61295aa3ae1989e5179c42e006d8e72e5beee08ae432db7
```

and, very important, if i relaunch the same command without modifying anything i'll obtain something like:

```
=> [ 1/11] FROM docker.io/library/node@sha256:fc738db1cbb81214be1719436605e9d7d84746e5eaf0629762aeba114aa0c28d                      0.0s
 => CACHED [ 2/11] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [ 3/11] COPY package*.json /app/                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [ 4/11] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [ 5/11] RUN npm install                                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [ 6/11] COPY  ./uselessfile.txt ./veryuseless.txt                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [ 7/11] COPY ./node_modules ./node_modules                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [ 8/11] COPY ./public ./public                                                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [ 9/11] COPY ./src ./src                                                                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [10/11] COPY ./build ./build                                                                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [11/11] RUN npm run build                                                                                                 0.0s
 => exporting to image
```

you can see a lot of cached layers.

So if you do any modication of the file `uselessfile.txt`, and then relaunch the `docker build` command, you'll obtain:

```bash
=> transferring context: 3.21MB                                                                                                  3.1s
 => [ 1/11] FROM docker.io/library/node@sha256:fc738db1cbb81214be1719436605e9d7d84746e5eaf0629762aeba114aa0c28d                      0.0s
 => CACHED [ 2/11] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [ 3/11] COPY package*.json /app/                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [ 4/11] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [ 5/11] RUN npm install                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [ 6/11] COPY  ./uselessfile.txt ./veryuseless.txt                                                                                0.1s
 => [ 7/11] COPY ./node_modules ./node_modules                                                                                      23.0s
 => [ 8/11] COPY ./public ./public                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [ 9/11] COPY ./src ./src                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [10/11] COPY ./build ./build                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [11/11] RUN npm run build                                                                                                       10.7s
 => => # babel-preset-react-app is part of the create-react-app project, which                                                           
 => => # is not maintianed anymore. It is thus unlikely that this bug will                                                               
 => => # ever be fixed. Add "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" to                                                       
 => => # your devDependencies to work around this error
```

as you can see, all the layers **after** the copy of `uselessfile.txt` will be recreated. Every. Single. Time.

### Another (superfaster) example

In the following example, i'll put the line `COPY  ./uselessfile.txt ./veryuseless.txt`

after a lot of layers, like this:

```yaml
FROM node as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim
RUN npm install

COPY ./node_modules ./node_modules  
COPY ./public ./public
COPY ./src ./src
COPY ./build ./build

# finally i do a build
RUN npm run build

# here insteal i put this AFTER all other folders and operations
COPY  ./uselessfile.txt ./veryuseless.txt

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Then i launch the `docker build` command and i will obtain:

```
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                 0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 482B                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:latest                                                                       1.2s
 => [auth] library/node:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                    6.0s
 => => transferring context: 3.21MB                                                                                                  5.4s
 => [ 1/11] FROM docker.io/library/node@sha256:fc738db1cbb81214be1719436605e9d7d84746e5eaf0629762aeba114aa0c28d                      0.0s
 => CACHED [ 2/11] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [ 3/11] COPY package*.json /app/                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [ 4/11] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [ 5/11] RUN npm install                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [ 6/11] COPY ./node_modules ./node_modules                                                                                      22.5s
 => [ 7/11] COPY ./public ./public                                                                                                   0.2s
 => [ 8/11] COPY ./src ./src                                                                                                         0.2s
 => [ 9/11] COPY ./build ./build                                                                                                     0.2s
 => [10/11] RUN npm run build                                                                                                       30.3s
 => [11/11] COPY  ./uselessfile.txt ./veryuseless.txt                                                                                0.0s 
 => exporting to image                                                                                                               5.7s 
 => => exporting layers
```

When i relaunch the `docker build` command even if i modify the `uselessfile.txt`

```
=> [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 37B                                                                                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:latest                                                                       0.6s
 => [ 1/11] FROM docker.io/library/node@sha256:fc738db1cbb81214be1719436605e9d7d84746e5eaf0629762aeba114aa0c28d                      0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                    3.1s
 => => transferring context: 3.21MB                                                                                                  2.6s
 => CACHED [ 2/11] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [ 3/11] COPY package*.json /app/                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [ 4/11] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [ 5/11] RUN npm install                                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [ 6/11] COPY ./node_modules ./node_modules                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [ 7/11] COPY ./public ./public                                                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [ 8/11] COPY ./src ./src                                                                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [ 9/11] COPY ./build ./build                                                                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [10/11] RUN npm run build                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [11/11] COPY  ./uselessfile.txt ./veryuseless.txt                                                                                0.3s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                               0.0s
 => => exporting layers
```

### Conclusions

Every layer depends on the preceding, and when you do as you do (good for certain production scopes), using `COPY . .`, any change on any file recreates a lot of layers.

Anyway, i suggest you to do a dockerfile for dev and one for production and keep it updated and similar.
For example in the dev one, you can copy the node_modules so you can skip the `npm install` command, or a mix of all these things. If you do a lot of editings on the `src` folder or `App.js` file, you don't have the need of recreate the node_modules every time on the docker build.

Moreover, you could edit the file directly on the container with vim to speed up you development.

Hope, it clearify!

Cose belle!

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, each instruction in a Dockerfile becomes roughly a layer in the final image. Every layer add more content to the bottom layer and, finally, all the layers compose a stack.

Whenever a layer changes, that layer need to rebuild and this affect all the layers that comes after it.

In your case, the issue that is preventing you to cache the initial layers is the `COPY . .` instruction. In fact, from the caching point of view that instruction is very inefficient since updating any file causes a reinstall of all files and dependencies every time you build the Docker image even if they were not changed.

If you cannot edit that instruction try to move it in order to be executed as late as possible, such as:

```
FROM myimage/node:14.19.3 as build
WORKDIR /home/node
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm run build
COPY . .
RUN rm -rf nginx/
```